# how to run laravel project on local using version 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, local

I am unable to run my laravel project locally i am using version 5.5 i have run command composer update and also composer install but i am unable to solve my error
when i run coommad
php artisan serve it says 
 [32mLaravel development server started on http://localhost:8000/[39m

I dont understand 32m and 39m here and when i hit url http://localhost:8000 on my browser the erros are dislaying

> Warning: require_once(G:\xampp\htdocs\project/public/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in G:\xampp\htdocs\project\server.php on line 21
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'G:\xampp\htdocs\project/public/index.php'(include_path='G:\xampp\php\PEAR') in 
>              G:\xampp\htdocs\project\server.php on line 21

can anyone please help me to sort out this issue.

Your help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: The 32m and 39m are just color codes. You can ignore that part. Can you show your directory schema? Does `G:\xampp\htdocs\project\public\index.php` exist?

Comment: yeah its exists

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` try running this. This command will clean up all compiled files and their paths.

Comment: okay the project is running on local but css and js files are not loading sucessfully images are crash and not showing any view completly

Comment: Make sure you're loading css and js files with absolute paths (ie starting with a slash and from the document root, `/css/file.css`) instead of relative paths

Comment: its like this    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="{{asset('images/favicon/apple-icon-57x57.png')}}">

Answer (score 0):

First you need to run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

this will clean up all compiled file.

Then you need to reference your css and JS like this

```
<script src="URL::to('/')/main.js"></script>
```

and

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="URL::to('/')/style.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

shahzad, Make sure the following things are intact.

1. Place all your assets(css, js, images) in the public folder
2. Check whether your asset URI pointing to assets in public folder under network tab of browser developer tools
3. Make sure your assets have the proper read and write permissions.